# Error with categorical dataset Seaborn scatterplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, categories, numeric

I have converted numerical to categorical data to be used in the legend of a Seaborn scatterplot.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [['Sample_1', 130, 325, 1989], ['Sample_2', 128, 348, 1999], ['Sample_3', 150, 258, 2018],['Sample_4', 171, 534, 2018], ['Sample_5', 171, 536, 2018], ['Sample_6', 278, 899, 2018],['Sample_7', 726, 1809, 2020]]  

df =pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'NROH',  'SROH', 'date'])
```

Conversion numerical to categorical:

```
df['date_cat'] = df['date'].astype('category')


sns.scatterplot(x='SROH', y='NROH', hue='date_cat', data=df)
```

Unfortunately, I go the following error message:

```
Cannot interpret 'CategoricalDtype(categories=[1989, 1999, 2018, 2020], ordered=False)' as a data type
```

Would anyone know why the data are not accepted as categorical values?

Comment: Are you working with the latest seaborn and pandas versions?

Comment: This plots as expected without error. **Tested in `python 3.10`, `pandas 1.4.2`, `matplotlib 3.5.1`, `seaborn 0.11.2`**. I'm voting to close this as not reproducible.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC and Trenton, it was indeed an update error. The script is working fine with Python 3.10.5, Pandas 1.4.3, and Seaborn 0.11.2. Thank you very much.